# Missing lib file, How to fix?

Tags: python, simpleitk

I get this error when trying to use SimpleITK package

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/omarkamal/anaconda3/envs/Radiology/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SimpleITK/_SimpleITK.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): image not found
```

I have tried to reinstall the package and update anaconda but no fix!

Any hints?

Comment: How are you installing SimpleITK?  That file should be in the SimpleITK package.  You can download the package directly and see all the files: https://anaconda.org/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/files